# Tournament graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

A tournament is a directed graph (digraph) obtained by assigning a direction for each edge in an undirected complete graph. That is, it is a directed graph in which every pair of vertices is connected by a single directed edge.

Data structure is adjacency matrix.

What s an algorithm to find if the graph is a tournament graph?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. Perhaps you could elaborate on your own thoughts regarding the problem and we could assist you wherever you've gotten stuck?

Comment: where did my comment go? Dav?

Comment: I have no idea; I saw it before and then it disappeared for me too.

Comment: How about this ? I start with a vertex then I do BFS and every vertex I visit i check if there is a back edge? Which should be less than O(n^2) ?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track, but remember that you also need to make sure the underlying undirected graph is complete.

Comment: There's no guarantee that your graph will be strongly connected, so BFS isn't guaranteed to reach all of the vertices in the graph.

Comment: Well BFS traversal quarantees (Except the errors in recursion) that every edge and vertex is visited by using Queue. The complexity would be Theta(E+V) ? because matrix look up would be constant time?

Comment: That guarantee is only true if every node can be *reached* from your starting node - which isn't necessarily the case here (envision a trivial example where all of the edges connected to your chosen starting node are directed towards it rather than away).

Comment: I understand but i still feel that in my question it s traversable.

Comment: Unless you mean that you're traversing the undirected version of the graph?

Comment: I cant do undirected that might create a back edge.

Comment: @Dav: It's not even guaranteed in that case, as the undirected version of the input graph may not actually be connected.

Comment: @bcat - since the initial problem statement says "every pair of vertices is connected by a single directed edge" I'd say that the undirected version would probably be complete (and regular, even?).

Comment: How about I do BFS traversal and then create a BFS tree with that and if there is a back edge from child to parent than it s not, otherwise it s. ?

Comment: Also, @unknown: keep in mind that your data structure here is an adjacency matrix; it takes O(n) time to look up the edges for a node. Thus just traversing the graph would still take O(n^2) time.

Comment: @Dav: My take on that was that it would still be possible to receive non-complete/non-connected graphs as input (in which case the program should reject them).

Comment: Why would it take O(n) for a lookup. isnt it O(1) ? We are assuming that the matrix is already populated.

Comment: @bcat: Even if one were building in checking for that, it should be fairly trivial - count how many edges you examine, make sure that number jives with how many edges you expect for that number of combinations.

Comment: @unknown: If I tell you to find me what edges exit node #3, how would you get me that in constant time?

Comment: @Dav: Yeah, fair enough.

Comment: I will look up to node #3 column, and yes that it will take n.  
But i m talking about , node 1 -> node 2 , check node 2 and node 1 in the matrix if it s 1 then there s a back edge, this is constant time look up.

Comment: Yes. But if your traversal takes O(n^2) - which it will, due to the need to look up edges in the adjacency matrix - then it doesn't matter if the back-edge check is constant time, the overall algorithm is still O(n^2).

Comment: fair enough. you want to write this as answer, so i can pick it up.

thanks.

Comment: Yet another way to look at this problem: since the number of edges is equal to the number of possible pairs of vertices, there will be n*(n-1)/2 edges, which is O(n^2). Your traversal is O(V+E), which thus is O(n+n^2), and thus is O(n^2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are n^2 entries in the adjacency matrix, and you need the info that is in all of the entries to solve the problem. (You need the 1's to check that the proper edges exist, and the 0's to check that the back-edges don't exist.) Thus since you have to read at least N^2 entries from the matrix, the overall problem must take at least O(N^2) time.

Regarding BFS search attempts: if your traversal takes O(n^2) - which it will, due to the need to look up edges in the adjacency matrix - then it doesn't matter if the back-edge check is constant time, the overall algorithm is still O(n^2).

Yet another way to look at this problem: since the number of edges is equal to the number of possible pairs of vertices, there will be n*(n-1)/2 edges, which is O(n^2). Your traversal is O(V+E), which thus is O(n+n^2), and thus is O(n^2).

Since the best-case time for this algorithm is O(n^2), you might as well simply loop through the upper-right half of matrix (above the diagonal) and check that for each of those entries, either a) it is 1, or b) its transpose equivalent is 1.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: missed the part where the graph was complete.

If `M` is your adjacency matrix, `Mt` is the transposed matrix, `~M` is the matrix with all the "bits" inverted, and `A^B` is the xor bit by bit between the two matrix.

Then the matrix is a tournament iff:

`~(M^Mt) = I`

Comment: That doesn't actually guarantee that all pairs of vertices are connected.

Comment: Foreach ? You cant do foreach, it will be O(n^2). What s the point of every edge? I d check it for every edge that i visited.

Comment: if your only data structure is an adjacency matrix, I don't think it can be anything else than O(n**2).

Comment: How? An adjacency matrix for a digraph (without edge weights) has `O(|V|^2)` boolean cells, where `|V|` is the number of vertices in the graph. Regardless of whether the graph is spare or dense, you still have to check `O(|V|^2)` matrix cells in order to visit every possible edge.

Comment: Actually, it's a fairly simple mental exercise to show that tonfa is right: there are n^2 entries in the adjacency matrix, and you need the info that is in all of the entries to solve the problem. (You need the 1's to check that the proper edges exist, and the 0's to check that the back-edges don't exist.) Thus since you have to read at least N^2 entries from the matrix, the overall problem must take at least O(N^2) time.

Answer (score 2):

To add to tonfa's comment:

**Brief**: The algorithm "for each i ≠ j, check to see that exactly one of (i,j) and (j,i) is in your graph" is asymptotically optimal.

**More detail:**
To just read in the adjacency matrix is going to take you Ω(n<sup>2</sup>) time.  So there is no way to solve this problem in o(n<sup>2</sup>) time.  But let's ignore the input.

Suppose that the matrix is already in memory.  To ensure that the undirected version of your graph is complete, you have to somehow determine that, for each i ≠ j, at least one of the edges (i,j) and (j,i) is in your graph.  As you have only the adjacency graph, this means you will have to at some point visit at least one of (i,j) or (j,i) for each i ≠ j.  There is no other way to guarantee completeness.  Verifying this will take n(n+1)/2 = O(n<sup>2</sup>) steps.

Comment: "More detail: To just read in the adjacency matrix is going to take you O(n2) time. So there is no way to solve this problem in o(n2) time." Not true. You could have multiple components that take O(n^2) time, and the result is still O(n^2). Remember that O() notation is *order*-based, not an actual function of the time.